# How to increase top margin in JavaScript popup from Mailchimp

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a popup subscription form to add in the header.php (Wordpress site).  The popup works, but I need to add code to have it display lower on the pages as the close button gets hidden as it's under the menu.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us14.list-manage.com","uuid":"2e3c50bfec9302388698ebcfa","lid":"b49da90d92"}) })</script>
```

Can anyone provide code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try increasing the z-index values so your navigation doesn't cover the popup? Also it's fairly easy to push it down by manipulating the margin.

CSS

```
<style>
    .mc-modal-bg {
        z-index: 10000001 !important;
    }
    .mc-modal {
        margin-top: 80px !important;
        z-index: 10000002 !important;
    }
</style>
```